# Why can't I call this object's function from an in-line anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Hey.')">Alert</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:alert('In anchor:\n' + objection.sustained());">Alert</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var objection = {
    sustained : (function() {return ("accroches-toi a ton reve")})
};

alert("In script: \n" + objection.sustained());

$("outdat").text( +"<br/>\n");
```

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/pAd9y/)

Just curious here, why can't I call `objection.sustained()` from an anchor tag, but it's OK to do it from the script region?

It seems to not even know the object exists when using the anchor. Happens in several major browsers so I believe this is by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable scope.

Fiddle is placing the variable in the document load scope so you're anchor code can not see it. As @kjy112 mentioned, remove this from those code blocks and all should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use No Wrapper(head) or No Wrapper(body) on JSFiddle